# iframe scrolling with jquery on chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had read a lot more about how to scroll using java script blah blah blah  and Jquery but nothing helps me. Is there any other way for performing this?

```
<iframe id="something" src="something" >
```

**and this**

```
$("something").scrollto(0,20);
```

**amd alot more**

Answer (score 0):

Now jquery sets .attr to scrolling="yes" and reloads the iframe!

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#button3").click(function () {
            $("#iframe_id").attr("scrolling", "yes");
            $('#iframe_id').attr("src", $('#iframe_id').attr("src"));
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77van/k8GhZ/10/